# Advantage of Using Theme & Skin File over CSS in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, themes, skin

I am developing a website in ASP.Net..
Is it good to develop the Styles using Themes with SkinFile or CSS as we use in HTML

Which is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes vs. Cascading Style Sheets

Themes are similar to cascading style sheets in that both themes and style sheets define a set of common attributes that can be applied to any page. However, themes differ from style sheets in the following ways:

```
*  Themes can define many properties of a control or page, not just style properties. For example, using themes, you can specify the graphics for a TreeView control, the template layout of a GridView control, and so on.
*  Themes can include graphics.
*  Themes do not cascade the way style sheets do. By default, any property values defined in a theme referenced by a page's Theme property override the property values declaratively set on a control, unless you explicitly apply the theme using the StyleSheetTheme property. For more information, see the Theme Settings Precedence section above.
*  Only one theme can be applied to each page. You cannot apply multiple themes to a page, unlike style sheets where multiple style sheets can be applied.
```

[Please go to msdn for more detail:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)

Comment: @Kaf: sorry. I didn't check yours link.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Controls can have properties set using skin files. For instance you can define that every button on your site needs the following properties:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
  BackColor="Red" 
  ForeColor="White" 
  Font-Name="Arial" 
  Font-Size="9px" />
```

It is *a* way to generalize styling for your website but nothing that can't be done using CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to your question, if all what you need is **styling**, then I would recommend the CSS way, especially because of its performance benefits, since it can be cached and does not cause any overhead in the Server.